# Is there any React Carousel library support load more (fetch new items from server) when users move to the last item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel

I'm having a React project with a carousel on the homepage (Using library @brainhubeu/react-carousel).

The items supplied to the carousel is limited (10 items) in the following code:

```
<Carousel
  arrows
  slidesPerPage={4}
  slidesPerScroll={1}
  autoPlay={1611000}
  infinite={false}
  clickToChange
  centered
  arrowLeft={<FaAngleDoubleLeft className="custom-carousel-control" />}
  arrowRight={<FaAngleDoubleRight className="custom-carousel-control" />}
  addArrowClickHandler
>
  {items}
</Carousel>;
```

Now I want to load more items whenever users click or scroll to end of the carousel (new items data will be fetched from server).

I've tried but I cannot find any carousel library that supports/has event when user click/scroll to end of carousel.

Is there any carousel library support that, or I have to create it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found and answer. `brainhubeu/react-carousel` library has an event `onChange`, but it only be called when I pass the props `value` to it (means I have to control the carousel value manually).

Base on that value and carousel breakpoints, I can calculate and check to see users is clicked/moved to the last carousel item, and then load more item from server.

```
let maxVisibleSlide = totalSlide - sliderPerPage + slideOffset;
if (targetSlide >= maxVisibleSlide) {
    // Do load more stuff here
}
```

When

1. sliderPerPage is calculated by screen width and carousel breakpoints
2. totalSlide is total item displaying in carousel
3. slideOffset is 2, default in carousel library
4. targetSlide if the value provided by onChange event (means the carousel item that the users want to see)

Sorry for my English, but hope this help someone!